# PHP use variables with google QR code api

Tags: php, google-api

i try to use google QR api to generate QR code with my data from php

```
<?php $qr = 'this is a QR code';?>  <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chl='.$qr.'">
```

i get img with data is .$qr. not text "this is a QR code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you forgot the PHP Tag in the HTML part.
And you should encode the string

```
<?php $qr = urlencode('this is a QR code'); ?>
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chl=<?= $qr ?>">
```